# Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone - IntelliSense problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have some problems with IntelliSense, before update IntelliSense auto-select corresponding type, f.e

```
class Test
{

}

//Main
{
  Test t = new //<- there IntelliSense automatic select 'Test' type, now IntelliSense select 'Test' but I have to press 'down' before 'enter' if I want it
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you already solved this problem, but since it is the first link I got on Google for "intellisense doesn't autoselect", I figured I might as well post the most likely reason IntelliSense acts like this:

You most likely forced it on for whatever reason, and accidentally used Ctrl+Alt+Space instead of Ctrl+Space. Using Ctrl+Alt+Space will make that extra bar go away and IntelliSense will behave as usual again.

I hope this helps people who just involuntarily *'discovered'* this feature and want IntelliSense behaving normal again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any other tools? That sounds similar to the Resharper behavior, more than the VS 2010.

Comment: No, I'm using express version (for Windows Phone)